# HTML: Creating a drop-down list within an inline list with only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal (inline) list and on some of them I need to have a drop-down list that only appears on hover. Everything seems to work right now but my issue is that the drop-down list does not appear as a separate list but as part of the rest of the list. I do not want to use JavaScript unless there is no other solution.

My code:

```css
.horizontalList ul {
list-style-type:none;
text-align: center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.horizontalList ul li {
display: inline;
position: relative;


}
.horizontalList ul li li a{
white-space:nowrap;
background-color: #300;
top:1.4em;
}
.horizontalList ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;

}
.horizontalList ul li a:hover {
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
.horizontalList ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 1.4em;
left: 0;
display: none;

}
.horizontalList ul > li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontalList">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Laptops</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Repairs and Servicing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">milks</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can u create it in jsfiddle and share link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by making the following changes:

- Add `position: relative;` to `.horizontalList ul li`. This will ensure that the sub menu is positioned relative to the containing `li`
- Add `position: absolute;` to `.horizontalList ul ul`. This will take it out of the normal flow and position it to the `top` and `left` values

**CSS:**

```
.horizontalList ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.horizontalList ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.horizontalList ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
}
.horizontalList ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #369;
}
.horizontalList ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.4em;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.horizontalList ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/s9z8rzt8/

Comment: What you gave me works great. Now I have another issue though. The text of the drop-down list (eggs and meat) is larger than the list name above (chickens) I used different names for the code I posted here as to not share actual content. For example make the chickens part of the code 123, the eggs part 12345 6789 and the meat part 987 54321, it's a width issue I guess but how do I change it?

Comment: How can I change the distance between each of the three outer list elements?

Comment: You'll need to show examples to ensure I'm understanding the issue correctly, however, I would say either add a `width` to `.horizontalList ul ul` **or** add a new rule `.horizontalList ul li li a { display: block; white-space: nowrap; }`. To change the distance between the three top level list items you can probably just add a margin to `.horizontalList ul li`.

Comment: Edited my question with actual content. Please check it in your example to see what I have. I added the white-space: nowrap; in the code but it gets thrown to the side. Edited my question with extra code

Comment: Glad I could help, did you sort the other issues?

Comment: Yes. I manually moved them a bit and they are fixed now. Also used the nowrap you gave me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is similar look as you had, just using something I put together a while ago as a template.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tagL4mo2/1/)

html

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Chickens</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">eggs</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">meat</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">milks</a></li>
```

css

```
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
    width:100%;

}
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}


#nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```

now just style it where necessary